# Knockout based application frameworks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I have been using knockout for developing front-end of our application. It has quiet impressive features and has simplified many complex data-binding scenarios for us. However it does not provide any guidance or constructs which can help in code-structuring. Are there any application frameworks built on top of Knockout and provide building modular, large scale JavaScript applications. For example in case of Backbone there are many application frameworks built on top of it(Marionette, Chaplin, Vertebrae, LayoutManager etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have built [BoilerplateJS](http://boilerplatejs.org/). It is not exactly a framework, but it is a reference architecture for large scale JavaScript projects. It can be used with knockoutjs, and several [examples](http://boilerplatejs.org/samples/productsuite/index.html#) are available.

It provides a guideline on how to:

1. Structure your code in to modules
2. How to manage your dependanceis (RequireJS is used here)
3. Client side routing
4. Unit testing
   .. and several other aspects that should be considered when building a large scale JavaScript application.